# Pickle variables and classes for save function in text adventure

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to make a save function in a text adventure.
The function must save some variables and parameters for the player.

I have tried to Google it and asking on forums, but I can't make it work.

The entire code is here: http://pastebin.com/8Y3PNnRx

The saving function should save the `player = player('Niels', 'Knight, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)` (line 417) and variables like `player.gold` and `player.potion` (line 420) at location `'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Desktop\\SmallDungeons\\save.dat'`

Thank you for your time!

Comment: have you tried `pickle.dump(player, 'player.pickle')`?

Answer (score 0):

You can save with:

```
pickle.dump((player, player.gold, player.potion), 'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Desktop\\SmallDungeons\\save.dat')
```

and load with

```
input2 = open('C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Desktop\\SmallDungeons\\save.dat','r')
data = pickle.load(input2)
player = data[0]
player.gold = data[1]
player.potion = data[2]
```

Comment: When doing so, I get this error: `TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)` - I added `,'w'` at the end of `pickle.dump()` - Otherwise I got this error: `TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)`

Answer (score 0):

For a minimal example, we build a class in `foo.py` (this is similar to your class `player`).

```
# foo.py
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x
  def bar(self):
    return self.x**2
```

Now we import it, and add some attributes (this is similar to you adding `player.gold`), and then pickle the class instance.  When we're done, we terminate the python interpreter session.

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 11 2014, 01:21:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from foo import Foo
>>> f = Foo(3)
>>> f.y = 10
>>> 
>>> import pickle
>>> with open('foobar.pkl', 'w') as pik:
...   pickle.dump(f, pik)
... 
>>>
```

Then, we restart the session, and load the pickle.

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 11 2014, 01:21:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pickle
>>> with open('foobar.pkl', 'r') as pik:
...   f = pickle.load(pik)
... 
>>> f.x
3
>>> f.bar()
9
>>> f.y
10
>>>
```

You'll see that just by saving the class instance, even the added attributes (like f.y) are preserved.  This is because `pickle` preserves a reference to your file (where to import it from) as well as any added attributes.  You can see this in the pickle string itself.

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 11 2014, 01:21:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from foo import Foo
>>> f = Foo(3)
>>> 
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.dumps(f)
"ccopy_reg\n_reconstructor\np0\n(cfoo\nFoo\np1\nc__builtin__\nobject\np2\nNtp3\nRp4\n(dp5\nS'x'\np6\nI3\nsb."
>>> 
>>> f.y = 10
>>> pickle.dumps(f)
"ccopy_reg\n_reconstructor\np0\n(cfoo\nFoo\np1\nc__builtin__\nobject\np2\nNtp3\nRp4\n(dp5\nS'y'\np6\nI10\nsS'x'\np7\nI3\nsb."
```

My suggestion is to use `pickle` protocol `-1`, as it makes the pickles smaller.  You add this flag to any of the places you use `dump` or `dumps`.

```
>>> pickle.dumps(f, protocol=-1)
'\x80\x02cfoo\nFoo\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02U\x01xq\x03K\x03sb.'
```

Comment: Note, for python `3.x`, you'll need to use `'wb'` and `'rb'` instead of `'w'` and `'r'`.