# Pickle user inputs - Python 3

Tags: python, pickle, python-3.4

I am pretty desperate, since I have tried to get this working in a long time.

I'm making a text adventure where some user inputs choose the player's hp, dmg, you name it.

I want to make a save function, but every time I load it, the player has default parameters.

Example:

```
class player:
    def __init__(self, hp, dmg):
        self.hp = hp
        self.dmg = dmg

def save(obj):
    save_file = open('C:\\Users\\XXXXX XXXX\\Desktop\\Game\\save.dat', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(obj, save_file)
    save_file.close()

def load():
    load_file = open('C:\\Users\\XXXXX XXXX\\Desktop\\Game\\save.dat', 'rb')
    loaded_game_data = pickle.load(load_file)
    return loaded_game_data

def start():
    player.hp = input('Player Hp')
    player.dmg = input('Player Dmg')

player = player(0, 0)

start()
```

Please don't just tell me what I do wrong, but also how to do it right. I really need this out of my head - Thank you!

I load the player with the following:

```
>>>print(player.hp)   # To make sure the HP is 0
0
>>>player.hp = 100    # I now change the HP to 100
>>>save(player)       # Saving the player with 800 HP and 0 DMG
                      # Restarting Python
>>>load()             # Loading the player
>>>print(player.hp)   # Check if the HP is 100 as I saved it.
0                     # The HP is 0...
                      # I expected 100 as I saved it.
```

Comment: What is your expected behavior ? At what point do you want to pickle values and when do you want to retrieve them ?

Comment: Just giving you a tip. I see you use a path to open a file. If you use the r option you can make sure a string is taken as raw input. Then you don't have to escape the backslash etc. For example: `open(r'C:\Program\File1.txt')`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pickle variables and classes for save function in text adventure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540153/pickle-variables-and-classes-for-save-function-in-text-adventure)

Comment: How are you restarting this script?  Show how you are creating the instance, and how you are using `save` and `load`, as well as how you are running the script… then stopping it, I assume… then restarting it.  How you are using the above code will make a difference in what you need to do to make it do what you want -- which is not clear from your question.  You'll get better answers the clearer you make the question with regard to what you want to do.

Comment: Are you doing `player = player(0,0)` inside your file?  if so, you are replacing the class `player` with an instance `player` that has zeros as it's attribute values every time.  If so, you should change the name of the instance to something other than the class name.  This matters because `pickle` imports classes by reference, and thus has to import and recreate the instance from the class every time -- not just "reconstitute" it without reading the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following runs well. Rename your `Player` class with an uppercase initial to avoid name conflicts. I added some test calls at the end, and the player is loaded with the intended (not default) stats.

```
import pickle

class Player:
    def __init__(self, hp, dmg):
        self.hp = hp
        self.dmg = dmg

def save(obj):
    save_file = open('save.dat', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(obj, save_file)
    save_file.close()

def load():
    load_file = open('save.dat', 'rb')
    loaded_game_data = pickle.load(load_file)
    return loaded_game_data

def start():
    player.hp = input('Player Hp: ')
    player.dmg = input('Player Dmg: ')

player = Player(0, 0)

start()
save(player)
loaded_player = load()
print loaded_player.hp, loaded_player.dmg
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! I've been working on this for days now ad it finally works thanks to you! :-)